# Bootstrap 4: Make responsive Float class with button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've problem with responsiveness when i've stacking button with float class. i want all my buttons stick at the end of the content.

```css
body {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.bg-a {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3 6px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

#img-top1,
#img-top2,
#img-top3 {
  border-radius: 0;
}

header .container .row div a.ss {
  padding: 5px 35px 10px 35px;
}

#img-top1 {
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#img-top3 {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Header -->
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" style="margin-top: 15px;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" style="padding: 0;">
        <a href="#" id="img-top1" class="ss btn btn-info float-right" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Primary link1</a>
        <a href="#" id="img-top2" class="ss btn btn-info float-right" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Primary link2</a>
        <a href="#" id="img-top3" class="ss btn btn-info float-right" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Primary link3</a>
        <br style="clear: both;"><br>
        <h4 style="background-color: skyblue; clear: both;">
          <a class="btn bg-a float-right" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-glide-g"></i></a>
          <a class="btn bg-a float-right" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a class="btn bg-a float-right" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a class="btn bg-a float-right" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
          <a class="btn bg-a float-right" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i></a>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header><br>
```

The button with id `img-top` is not responsive, meanwhile the icon button with the same class is responsive (maybe because of the small size). How can i make it responsive?
the example of web : [RHT Academy](https://www.rhtacademy.com/)

[image: Picture for more details]

Comment: Please help anyone. Thx

Comment: It's not really clear what you want.  There are structural elements I would recommend to *enhance* responsive behavior and provide you more flexibility, but "more responsive" is not enough information to assist you.

Comment: And then can you give the example for what you recommend to enhance responsive behavior even not using float class? What I really want is the primary link button is stay at the top and at the right end of the content no matter what the screen size is. I've already give the example of web so you can clearly see what i want.
@RobertC

Comment: What i did is make 3 buttons. but i realize maybe is not the 3 buttons, but only 1 div with 3 link text?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service; it is for code-fixing.  Clarify what it is you expect to happen in your code that ISN'T and we can better address your post.